# Modify an array with split with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Below is my code:
I am trying to get the 2nd item in the array after split(which will always be 3 digit)
and trying to separate that with "-" by 1st and second third character.
So, '021' should become '0', '21' and be attached to the same array.

```
var q = {f_seq: "14-021-1721307"};
p = q.f_seq.split('-');
p[1] = p[1].substr(0, 1);
p[2] = p[2].substr(1, 2);
console.log(p);
```

current output:

```
['14', '0', '72']
```

expected output:

```
['14', '0', '21', '1721307']
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mutating `p` after you split the original string, create a new array to hold the output. It will be easier to understand what is happening.

```js
var q = {f_seq: "14-021-1721307"};
p = q.f_seq.split('-');
let out = [p[0],p[1][0],p[1].substr(1,2), p[2]];
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

Randomly playing with newer array features since I keep forgetting they're there:

```js
const str = '14-021-1721307'
const split = str.split('-').flatMap(
    (s, i) => i === 1 ? [s[0], s.substr(1)] : s
)
console.log(split)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` method which dose exactly what you want:

```
let q = {f_seq: "14-021-1721307"};
let p = q.f_seq.split('-');
p.splice(1,1,p[1][0],p[1].slice(1))
console.log(p)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var q = { f_seq: "14-021-1721307" };
p = q.f_seq.split('-');
//p[1] = p[1].substr(0, 1);
//p[2] = p[2].substr(1, 2);

console.log(p);
// => [ '14', '021', '1721307' ]
```

`.split` does not modify an array, it creates a new one and returns it.

Then you can apply your second modification on `p[1]` to separate `0` and `21` but it would be better to explain the goal so we can provide a real solution that works in every case.